# Lower CPU Usage in Small Simulation

Tags: c

I am a beginner C Programmer solving some programming exercises and came across a task in which I have to simulate the behaviour of ants in a 50x50 grid. At this moment, I'm just making them move to a random field.
Code:

```
    while (!quit)
    {
    Update();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
        {
            if (gebiet[i][j] == 'a')
            {
                ameisenf = ameisen[i][j];
                for (int k = 0; k < ameisenf; k++)
                {
                    ameisen[i][j]--;
                    gebiet[i][j] = ' ';
                    val = rand() % (7 + 1 - 0) + 0;
                    switch(val)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            gebiet[i][j + 1] = 'a';
                            ameisen[i][j + 1]++;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            gebiet[i][j - 1] = 'a';
                            ameisen[i][j - 1]++;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            gebiet[i + 1][j + 1] = 'a';
                            ameisen[i + 1][j + 1]++;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            gebiet[i + 1][j - 1] = 'a';
                            ameisen[i + 1][j - 1]++;
                            break;                              
                        case 4:
                            gebiet[i + 1][j] = 'a';
                            ameisen[i + 1][j]++;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            gebiet[i - 1][j - 1] = 'a';
                            ameisen[i - 1][j - 1]++;
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            gebiet[i - 1][j + 1] = 'a';
                            ameisen[i - 1][j + 1]++;
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            gebiet[i - 1][j] = 'a';
                            ameisen[i - 1][j]++;
                            break;                              
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    getchar();
}
```

The Update() function just draws the board.
When viewed in task manager, it shows that the program is using 2 percent of my CPU, is this normal for such a simulation or is it because I have an older cpu? And how could I possibly lower the CPU usage? I tried adding usleep(), but it increased the cpu usage to 3 percent.

Comment: You didn't show us all your code, but if your simulation is running as fast as it can, I would expect it to use 100% of the CPU!  So if you're only getting 2%, that sounds amazing, and I wouldn't worry about trying to speed it up.  (Nor is there probably a good way to.)  If necessary,  would put in a `usleep` call to slow things down a bit to make the simulation more pleasant to watch, not to make it "more efficient".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand cpu usage a bit better now

Comment: Comment out the call to Update() and compare.  I/O is slow and doesn't drive up processor usage.

Comment: The slow part may be `getchar()`, because that'll block until `stdin` provides input or the write end corresponding to it is closed. If it's waiting for actual terminal input, that would explain why the processor is idle 98% of the time. It's waiting for the *user* most of the time already, no point in explicitly `sleep()`ing.